# how to loop through files with some number format using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to iterate through some files. The difference in those files are just a number appended to it.

I want to do something like this -

```
SET /A COUNT=1
for %%I in (\\bay-e!COUNT!\e$\sat\logs\BAY-E!COUNT!.Log.2012-03-  12.log) do (
@echo %%~zI
SET /A COUNT+=1
)
```

I do not see this working. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are on Windows.
The way to do it is something like

```
FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,100) DO ECHO \\bay-%%G\e$\sat\logs\BAY-%%G.log
```

There are very useful unofficial Windows .BAT docs, here is the one for FOR/L: http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html

*Note*: On the command line, use %G, only a .BAT file needs %%G